# Set variables to 404 in zend framework 2

Tags: variables, view, controller, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404

In my controller I throw a 404 response after an If statement, something like that :

```
    if ($foo) {
        $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
        return; 
    }
```

Then, I would like to send some variables to my 404 page. In my mind, I want to do something like that :

```
    $this->getResponse()->setVariables(array('foo' => 'bar', 'baz' => 'bop'));
    $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
    return;
```

It's not the good solution, so how I have to do that ?

And after, how to get these variables in my 404 view ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh god..

I was so dumb

Solution :

```
if ($foo) {
    $this->getResponse()->setStatusCode(404);
    return array('myvar' => 'test');
}
```

In 404.phtml :

```
<?php echo $this->myvar; ?>
```

Comment: for zf1 it's $this->getResponse()->setHttpResponseCode(404);

Answer (score 1):

I've come to this question from Google and my issue was a bit more difficult. Since 404 error could be thrown from absolutely unpredictable url, you can't be sure you catched it in some controller. Controller – is too late to catch 404 error.

The solution in my case was to catch an `EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR` and totally rebuild `viewModel`. Cavern is that layout – is a root `viewModel`, and content appended into layout by default is another `viewModel` (child). These points are not such clear described in official docs.

Here is how it can look like in your `Module.php`:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
{
    $app = $event->getParam( 'application' );
    $eventManager = $app->getEventManager();


    /** attach Front layout for 404 errors */
    $eventManager->attach( MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH_ERROR, function( MvcEvent $event ){

        /** here you can retrieve anything from your serviceManager */
        $serviceManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $someVar = $serviceManager->get( 'Some\Factory' )->getSomeValue();

        /** here you redefine layout used to publish an error */
        $layout = $serviceManager->get( 'viewManager' )->getViewModel();
        $layout->setTemplate( 'layout/start' );

        /** here you redefine template used to the error exactly and pass custom variable into ViewModel */
        $viewModel = $event->getResult();
        $viewModel->setVariables( array( 'someVar' => $someVar ) )
                  ->setTemplate( 'error/404' );
    });
}
```