# Set & Access Variables in error Page ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

```
class FrontController extends AbstractActionController {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->layout()->setting_data = $this->getSetting()->getSettingContent(1);
        return array();
    }

}

public function getSetting() {
    return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Front/Model/Setting');
}
```

class Setting extends AbstractTableGateway {

```
public function __construct($adapter) {
    $this->table = 'setting';
    $this->adapter = $adapter;
}
public function fetchAll() {
    return $this->select();
}
public function getSettingContent($id){
    $id  = (int) $id;
    $rowset = $this->select(array('id'=>$id));
    if (!$row = $rowset->current()){
        throw new \Exception ('Row not found');
    }
    return $row;
}
```

}

My Module.php file is after your replay is:

```
namespace Front;
/*use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;*/
class Module
{

public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $event = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $event->attach('render', function($e) {
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();
        $dbadapter = $serviceManager->get('Zend\Db\Adapter');

        /*
         * Through this adapter make sql-request and
         * fetch data that you need and give it to
         * $setting_data variable
         */

        $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('setting_data', $setting_data);
    });
}
    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array('Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' =>
            array('namespaces' =>
                array(__NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,),
            ),
        );
    }
/*    public function init(ModuleManager $moduleManager)
    {
        $sharedEvents = $moduleManager->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEvents->attach(__NAMESPACE__, 'dispatch', function($e) {
            // This event will only be fired when an ActionController under the MyModule namespace is dispatched.
            $controller = $e->getTarget();
            $controller->layout('layout/frontlayout');
        }, 100);
    }
*/
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
    // Add this method:
    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
        'Zend\Db\Adapter' => function($sm){
            $global_config = $sm->get('Configuration');
            $db_params = $global_config['db'];
            return new Adapter($db_params);
        },
            'factories' => array(
                'Front\Model\AlbumTable' =>  function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\AlbumTable($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
                'Front\Model\Cms' =>  function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\Cms($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
                'Front\Model\Setting' =>  function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\Setting($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
                'Front\Model\Slider' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\Slider($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
                'Front\Model\Schedule' => function($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                    $table     = new \Front\Model\Schedule($dbAdapter);
                    return $table;
                },
            ),
        );
    }
}
?>
```

In my controller(Front) I can fetch data from database and set in layout.(Here Setting_data).

I can easily fetch set data index view page if my action/method is perfect.

but i want to this set data in error page also means if my action/method not found page.

How can i will get this data.?

I don't want to set static data I want to call dynamic data and set it in one variable(Here setting_data). I want to access this variable in my error page layout.

OR

***Which controller call for error page?***

Comment: Not exactly what you ask, but it may be interesting [_ONE_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18776447/1728687), [_TWO_](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16853835/1728687)

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I have seen both link but both are for static variable not for dynamic data set in it.Which controller called for error page? so I have updated my questions please see and give me answer.

Comment: It depends on error. For example, when you request url, which not match any route, then no any controller fired. When error throws manually inside controller, then you may render error page as you do it in normal request processing. What exactly error you want to process?

Comment: I used this setting_data variable's value in footer content, if  page found then there is no issue but If Page not found then I want to get this setting_data variable's value in footer layout but I got undefined variable setting_data.How can I fix this error.

Comment: What exactly contains that variable $setting_data?

Comment: Thanks Microbe.  MY $setting_data contains contact details and social media URL. This Data fetch from Database and set into variable $setting_data.Now Please help me.

Comment: Ok i know how to implement what you need but please show me how you fetch this data from database (show controller's method `getSettingContent()`)

Comment: Hi Microbe I have updated my question please see it.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. As I understood from our conversation (see comments), your `$setting_data` variable not depends on any controller environment but only on some database data. In that case the first link from my first comment is what you need.

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $event = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();

    $event->attach('render', function($e) {
        $serviceManager = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager();

        $setting = $serviceManager->get('Front/Model/Setting');
        $setting_data = $setting->getSettingContent(1);

        $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('setting_data', $setting_data);
    });
}
```

Comment: /*
         * Through this adapter make sql-request and
         * fetch data that you need and give it to
         * $setting_data variable
         */ how can I fetch select query here?

Comment: In you example `$rowset = $this->select(array('id'=>$id));`. Please give me the code of `select()` method.

Comment: these select function is zf2 library function so i just passed table name and id so its returns all data related to that. but tell me simple query select * from settingtable. how can i execute it

Comment: as per your answer I have change in my module.php file but its returns error like this: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter' in E:\wamp\www\ehr\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php on line 495

Comment: I updated my answer. Check it. Sorry, all is more easily than i think. You don't need implement 'Zend\Db\Adapter'.

Comment: Arrrgghhh sorry! Delete string where $dbadapter and delete its implementation from `getServiceconfig()` method. I updated my answer.

Comment: That's true. I want this solution. Thank you Very much . You saved my lot of hour and my pain. Thanks a lot. Cheers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43993/discussion-between-chirag-and-microbe)