# Variable Can't access outside ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, bootstrapping

My Bootstrap Function is like this:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $event = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $event->getSharedManager()
          ->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController',
                    'dispatch',
                array($this, 'settingUpControllerVariables'), 100
        );
    }

    public function settingUpControllerVariables(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        $controller = $e->getTarget();

        //check if logged in, setting up the userid variable of controllers
        if ($e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
                            ->get('AuthService')
                            ->hasIdentity()) {
            $users = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()
                            ->get('SanAuth\Model\AuthStorage')->read();

            $controller->userid = $users['id'];
            $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('user_data', $controller->userid);
        }
    }
```

I want to check user is login or not so for that I am check it in bootstrap action and assign its value if user login.This functionality related to assigning variable its working fine but when I want to access this variable's value in layout page but all time its returns undefined variable.**WHY?**

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting of variable must occur after render event, because view model appear after that event. But I may be wrong.

Instead of

```
$e->getViewModel()->setVariable('user_data', $controller->userid);
```

try this:

```
$eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
$eventManager->attach('render', function($e) use ($controller){
    $e->getViewModel()->setVariable('user_data', $controller->userid);
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774019/set-access-variables-in-error-page-zf2/20800544#20800544)

Comment: How Can I access this user_data in my footer.phtml file. when i used echo $user_data all time its return undefined variable.